# Associative relationship for "manager working term"

Tags: database-design, erd

I am creating ERD following some database design requirements.

This specific part on the ERD is what I am trying to represent. [image]

I made the `MANAGEMENT` entity because it's related to `DATE_ACCEPTANCE`, which is about managers working term (when it's started, who is the manager at a specific time).

I'm currently not sure about the relation between `MANAGEMENT` and 2 other entities in this ERD as it might affect the conversion to relational model.

Comment: it would be enough to add  the two columns of management zo the employee table, also why is there a relationship between management dan department without any column

Comment: To @nbk : Are you talking about the FKs that specify the relationship? If yes, I will add them in the relational model step. Secondly, the requirement is actually on the `DEPARTMENTS`, that is, each department must have a manager and his/her date of acceptance. The `MANAGE` recursive relationship has nothing to do with that requirement I think (like supervising).

Comment: you have a relations hip between management and department but neither manager code in department nor department code in management

Comment: To @nbk : I believe when I translate this into relational model, `MANAGER_CODE` would be add to `DEPARTMENTS` as FK. At first, I let `MANAGER_CODE` and `DATE_ACCEPTANCE` be in `DEPARTMENTS`. Then my lecturer advised me to establish another relationship between `DEPARTMENTS` and `EMPLOYEES`, that's why we are here. Do you find my question too confusing? Would it be better if I add full DB requirements and full of my current ERD to this question?

Comment: so doesn't sql work, you need column(s) that references the other tables prmary key or unique/ index constaraint

Comment: To @nbk : This ERD is just about the structure of the DB, with those specified relations, constraints will be added when we implement this physically using DML I believe.

Comment: you need correct table and relationship to determine if something is wrong or cqn be improved and my first comment already in short mangement is not needed for this design

Comment: To @nbk : I think adding `MANAGER_CODE` role and `DATE_ACCEPTANCE` to `EMPLOYEES` would create a bad design due to potential redundancies.

Comment: No only if allow multiple managers or a persons that belong to more than one department, so that you have a m:n relationship, but for now it seems you have only 1:1 relationships aka one manager one department, so if management has only 1 additional attribute and when every manager is a manager or have only 1 manager addind the date column that is only filled when a employee is manager, would not created refundencies, but that all is only my opinion

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Schema design is an [iterative](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative) (and links within) process - design schema_1, code, test code, find bugs (and there **will** be bugs), design schema_2... and so on (rinse and repeat) until you have a system which matches your requirements.